# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_addons.image' has no attribute 'gradients'

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, neural-network, gradient-descent, tensorflow-addons

I am working on a project on google colab where I need to visualize gradient maps for an image using TensorFlow and TensorFlow Addons. I have defined a function `plot_gradient_maps` that uses `tfa.image.gradients` to compute gradients. However, I am encountering an `AttributeError` stating that the module `tensorflow_addons.image` has no attribute `gradients`.

**Here is the relevant part of the code:**

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

def input_img(path): #read source image file
    image = tf.image.decode_png(tf.io.read_file(path))
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [160,160])
    return image
def normalize_image(img): #normalise image
    grads_norm = img[:,:,0]+ img[:,:,1]+ img[:,:,2]
    grads_norm = (grads_norm - tf.reduce_min(grads_norm))/ (tf.reduce_max(grads_norm)- tf.reduce_min(grads_norm))
    return grads_norm

def plot_maps(img1, img2,vmin=0.3,vmax=0.7, mix_val=2): 
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(15,45))
    plt.subplot(1,3,1)
    plt.imshow(img1,vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cmap="terrain")
    plt.title('Saliency map')
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.subplot(1,3,2)
    plt.imshow(img2, cmap = "terrain")
    plt.title('Input image')
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.subplot(1,3,3)
    plt.imshow(img1*mix_val+img2/mix_val, cmap = "terrain" )
    plt.title('Overlayed image')
    plt.axis("off")
def plot_orig_img(filepath):
    img_path = filepath
    input_im = input_img(img_path)
    input_im = tf.keras.applications.efficientnet_v2.preprocess_input(input_im)
    plt.imshow(normalize_image(input_im[0]))
    plt.axis('off');
    return input_im
def plot_gradient_maps(input_im): 
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(input_im)
        result_img = model(input_im)
        max_idx = tf.argmax(result_img, axis=1)
        max_score = result_img[0, max_idx[0]]

    # Use tfa.image.gradients 
    grads = tfa.image.gradients(max_score, input_im) 
    plot_maps(normalize_image(grads[0]), normalize_image(input_im[0]))


input_im = plot_orig_img(filepath="/content/work_directory/test/glaucoma/1209_right.jpg");
plot_gradient_maps(input_im)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-26a30edde128> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 plot_gradient_maps(input_im)

<ipython-input-119-b5bf95270540> in plot_gradient_maps(input_im)
     48 
     49     # Use tfa.image.gradients
---> 50     grads = tfa.image.gradients(max_score, input_im)
     51     plot_maps(normalize_image(grads[0]), normalize_image(input_im[0]))
     52 

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_addons.image' has no attribute 'gradients'
```

The gradients function seems to be missing from the tfa.image module. I have checked the documentation, but I couldn't find any information on this specific issue.

I attempted to use tfa.image.gradients for computing gradients, following the examples and documentation available. However, the AttributeError mentioned above was encountered.

I expected the code to execute without errors and generate gradient maps using the tfa.image.gradients function.

How to correctly use `tfa.image.gradients`? or suggest an alternative approach for computing gradients in TensorFlow Addons.

Comment: Looking at [the API](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image), this function does not seem to exist.